# Design application using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, scala-2.11

Its a bit architectural kind of question. I need to design an application using Spark and Scala as the primary tool. I want to minimise the manual intervention as much as possible.

I will receive a zip with multiple files having different structures as an input at a regular interval of time say, daily. I need to process it using Spark . After transformations need to move the data to a back-end database.

Wanted to understand the best way I can use to design the application. 
What would be the best way to process the zip ?
Is the Spark Streaming can be considered as an option looking at the frequency of the file ?
What other options should I take into consideration?

Any guidance will be really appreciable.

Comment: It's off topic for SO. However you can try to implement steps and ask for help with them

Comment: Leaving the architectural part , how can I work with a zip in Spark with multiple files having different structures as an input.

Answer (score 0):

Its a broad question, there are batch options and stream options not sure your exact requirements. you may start your research here: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-FileStreamSource.html